# Tkinter TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I'm having a chat client that's using Tkinter. Works good on linux, but gives me an error on windows.

```
Error: TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

I have the GUI built with Tkinter. I've built a class called GUI, which inherits the `threading.thread` class. I have a socket connection to the server. The `sent` method is activate when I press enter in the text field. The `recv` method, runs on another thread, started before I started the mainloop for the GUI object.

Here is my GUI class:

```
from __future__ import division
from Tkinter import *
from utils.sound import playsound
import threading
import config.config
import os

# TKinter GUI class
class GUI(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, client_handler):
        self._base = None
        self._message_box = None
        self._scrollbar = None
        self._message_txt = None
        self._menu_bar = None

        self._play_sound = True

        self._locked = True
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        self._client_handler = client_handler
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    # start looping
    def loop(self):
        self.start()

    # start doing work
    def run(self):
        # main Form
        self._base = Tk()
        self._base.title(config.config.WINDOW_TITLE)
        self._base.geometry("450x480")
        self._base.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
        self._base.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)       # exit event

        # menu bar
        self._menu_bar = Menu(self._base)
        self._menu_bar.add_command(label="Disable sound", command=lambda : self.control_sound(self._menu_bar))
        self._base.config(menu=self._menu_bar)

        # log box
        self._message_box = Text(self._base, bd=0, bg="white", height="8", width="50", font="Arial")
        self._message_box.config(state=DISABLED)
        # scrollbar to chat window
        self._scrollbar = Scrollbar(self._base, command=self._message_box.yview)
        self._message_box['yscrollcommand'] = self._scrollbar.set

        # box to enter message
        self._message_txt = Text(self._base, bd=0, bg="white", width="29", height="5", font="Arial")
        self._message_txt.bind("<Return>", self.enter_pressed)
        self._message_txt.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", self.enter_released)

        # place widgets on form
        self._scrollbar.place(x=430, y=6, height=386)
        self._message_box.place(x=6, y=6, height=386, width=425)
        self._message_txt.place(x=6, y=401, height=70, width=437)

        # loop
        self.set_locked(False)

        # update ui
        #self.update_ui()
        self._base.mainloop()

    # ------------------------------------------------
    # Called by different thread
    # This is the method which throws the error !!!
    # show ---- line in message box
    # ------------------------------------------------
    def new_line(self):
        self._message_box.config(state=NORMAL)     # breaks on this line
        self._message_box.insert(END, '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n')
        self._message_box.yview(END)
        self._message_box.config(state=DISABLED)
```

I've tried to make the GUI class inherit just the `object` (nothing actually). In this way, it doesn't throw me the error on Windows but the GUI is freezing.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: All tkinter interactions must be on the same thread that created the root window. The best practice is to put tkinter in the main thread, and put any other code such as a socket listener in a worker thread.